# How can I capture low resolution video via phoneGap 3.x.x?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, video-capture

I have written code to capture video using phonegap, its working fine. But I need to capture low resolution. I want to change its height and width on run time. 
Please help me.

```
    function CaptureVideo()
{
    navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError,{quality: 30,limit: 1,targetWidth: 200,targetHeight: 200});
}
```

It does not take height and width when I capture.

Comment: Please post the code you've got so we can help you

Comment: navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {quality: 30,limit: 1, targetWidth: 200,targetHeight: 200});    But it donot take height and width.

Comment: You should [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) to include your code by clicking the "edit" link below the tags, just to the right of the up/downvote buttons. You should format the code in the post by clicking the `{}` button, pressing `CTRL-K`, or indenting by 4 spaces